# jQuery Form - Serialize into multi dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, forms

I need to get value from `form`, format it to JSON and post it via AJAX. This is the format I want to achieve:

```
{
  items: [
    { id: 7, name: 'Book', price: 5.7 },
    { id: 5, name: 'Pencil', price: 2.5 }
  ]
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```js
(function($){
  
  var $form = $('form');
  
  // serializeArray format is way off from what I need
  var rawData = $form.serializeArray();
  console.log(rawData)
  
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <h2>Product 1</h2>
    <input type="hidden" name="items[0][id]" value="7">
    <input type="text" name="items[0][name]" value="Book">
    <input type="number" name="items[0][price]" value="5.7">
  </fieldset>
  
  <fieldset>
    <h2>Product 2</h2>
    <input type="hidden" name="items[1][id]" value="5">
    <input type="text" name="items[1][name]" value="Pencil">
    <input type="number" name="items[1][price]" value="2.5">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Should I loop and use regex to parse the `name`? or is there built-in way?

I can change the `<form>` format if needed.

Comment: No, I mean I want to get all the data from the input to form that JSON. I need to post it via Ajax. I'll edit the Question to make it more clear

Comment: serialize won't work here, you need to do it manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at this approach. We can't just use `$.serializeArray()` but also we need some custom code as follows. Actually we need to iterate over all `<fieldset>` to get JSON as we needed:

```js
(function($) {

  var $form = $('form');
  var fieldSets = $form.find("fieldset");
  var result = {
    items: []
  };
  fieldSets.each(function() {
    var fields = {};
    $.each($(this).serializeArray(), function() {
      fields[this.name] = this.value;
    });
    result.items.push(fields);
  });

  console.log(result);
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <h2>Product 1</h2>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="7">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="Book">
    <input type="number" name="price" value="5.7">
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <h2>Product 2</h2>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="5">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="Pencil">
    <input type="number" name="price" value="2.5">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Note:** Modified the HTML a bit as instead of `name="items[0][id]"` i have given as `name="id"`

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the simpler solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the default serialization here, instead you can do a manual serialization like

```js
(function($) {

  var $fieldsets = $('form fieldset');

  var items = $fieldsets.map(function(i, fs) {
    var obj = {};
    $(fs).find('input').each(function() {
      obj[this.name.match(/\[([^\[]*)\]$/)[1]] = this.value;
    });
    return obj;
  }).get();

  var rawData = {
    items: items
  };
  console.log(rawData)

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <h2>Product 1</h2>
    <input type="hidden" name="items[0][id]" value="7">
    <input type="text" name="items[0][name]" value="Book">
    <input type="number" name="items[0][price]" value="5.7">
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <h2>Product 2</h2>
    <input type="hidden" name="items[1][id]" value="5">
    <input type="text" name="items[1][name]" value="Pencil">
    <input type="number" name="items[1][price]" value="2.5">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need to parse the `name` field yourself. There is no automated method of parsing a custom field.  There are, of course, multiple methods of doing so.

NOTE: I'm assuming that your `name="items[0][id]"` field specifies that this must be the 0th item in the resulting array, and that such sets of `<input>` fields are not, necessarily, in ascending order by item # within the DOM. In other words, the `item[N]` should be controlling over it being the Qth `<fieldset>` in the `<form>`.

You could use `serializeArray()` and then process that data:

```js
(function($){
  
  var $form = $('form');
  var data = $form.serializeArray();
  var result =  {items:[]};
  data.forEach(function(input){
    nameArray = input.name.split(/[[\]]/);
    item = nameArray[1];
    prop = nameArray[3];
    if(typeof result.items[item] !== 'object'){
      result.items[item]={};
    }
    if(typeof result.items[item][prop] !== 'undefined'){
      //Consistency check the name attribute
      console.log('Warning duplicate "name" property =' + input.name);
    }
    result.items[item][prop]=input.value;
  });
  console.log(result);
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <h2>Product 1</h2>
    <input type="hidden" name="items[0][id]" value="7">
    <input type="text" name="items[0][name]" value="Book">
    <input type="number" name="items[0][price]" value="5.7">
  </fieldset>
  
  <fieldset>
    <h2>Product 2</h2>
    <input type="hidden" name="items[1][id]" value="5">
    <input type="text" name="items[1][name]" value="Pencil">
    <input type="number" name="items[1][price]" value="2.5">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Or, you could directly process it from the DOM:

```js
(function($){

  var result =  {items:[]};
 
  $('form fieldset input').each(function(){
    nameArray = this.name.split(/[[\]]/);
    item = nameArray[1];
    prop = nameArray[3];
    if(typeof result.items[item] !== 'object'){
      result.items[item]={};
    }
    if(typeof result.items[item][prop] !== 'undefined'){
      //Consistency check the name attribute
      console.log('Warning duplicate "name" property =' + this.name);
    }
    result.items[item][prop]=this.value;
  });
  console.log(result);
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <h2>Product 1</h2>
    <input type="hidden" name="items[0][id]" value="7">
    <input type="text" name="items[0][name]" value="Book">
    <input type="number" name="items[0][price]" value="5.7">
  </fieldset>
  
  <fieldset>
    <h2>Product 2</h2>
    <input type="hidden" name="items[1][id]" value="5">
    <input type="text" name="items[1][name]" value="Pencil">
    <input type="number" name="items[1][price]" value="2.5">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: why do you think this solution will help OP?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The `items[0]` is just example to avoid duplicate name. I guess it's okay to use duplicate name like just `id` or `name` like the answer by vijayP

Comment: @DarcCode, Thanks. It is often convenient for the `name` attribute to be duplicated (it can be used to group elements) (e.g `getElementsByName()`). Another time, please mention in the question that the HTML can be changed. When I read the question, I assumed you are attempting to use JavaScript to get to your desired JSON based on HTML which was in that exact format. Both that assumption, and vijayP's assumption (HTML can be changed as convenient) are valid given the way it is written. Indicating in the question which is the case would help people provide you with better answers.

Comment: @Makyen Thanks for the advice, I'll give more details next time I put a question.